# How I could apply digital sign in PDF at oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, digital-signature, apex-code, digital

If any body has knowledge regarding attach digital signature with pdf by oracle apex please share.

I have two scenario,

1. Create report by BI publisher or download from Interactive report, add digital signature on that time based on specific user.
2. Add digital signature on existing PDF by specific user at oracle apex.

Please share your knowledge with step by step procedure. As I am Novice.

Comment: Start with: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/bi/analytics-server/administer-publisher-oas/use-digital-signature-pdf-document.html

Comment: How could I Add digital signature on existing PDF by specific user at oracle apex?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have the ability to do that natively. You'd need a third-party product like DBSign to add that capability. https://dbsign.com/index.html